# Laravel throwing error for commented code?

Tags: laravel

Strangest thing, I've commented out some code in my blade template to debug / test other code - but now Laravel is throwing an error because of something within the commented code?

Commented code:

```
{{--
                                @if ($students)
                                    @php
                                        $row_count = 0;
                                        $previous_student_id = null;
                                    @endphp
                                    @foreach ($students as $student)
                                        <tr>
                                        @if ($student->student_id==$previous_student_id)
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>{{$student->academic_institution}}</td>
                                            <td class="ctal">{{$student->current_year}}</td>
                                        @else
                                            @php($row_count++)
                                            <td>{{$row_count}}</td>
                                            <td class="sml">{{$student->student_name .' '.$student->student_middle_names .' '. $student->student_surname}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$student->academic_institution}}</td>
                                            <td class="ctal">{{$student->current_year}}</td>
                                        @endif
                                            @php($previous_student_id=$student->student_id)
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
--}}
```

Error being the line: `@if ($student->student_id==$previous_student_id)` with the error:

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: previous_student_id (View: /xxx)

Why is it processing a blade comment??? Surely this is a bug?

`Laravel Framework 7.7.1`

Comment: You can check directly in your rendered template see why you are getting this

Comment: DId you ran `php artisan clear-compiled`?

Comment: The error / error line is referencing the commented out code, I shouldnt be getting it at all @ChristopheHubert because its a comment.

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi - running that didnt help. I'm confident this must be a bug.

Comment: could you remove the code entirely to confirm it?

Comment: yes - I have done this already, if i remove the comment - the code works